# PN junction depletion capacitance

Tags: semiconductors

[image]

I am having difficulty understanding the PN junction capacitance.

I can't seem to figure out what exactly forms the two plates of the PN junction capacitance and what is the positive and negative charges on each side?

From the analogy of a parallel plate capacitance, I always assumed that the plate itself was infinitely thin and that positive charges would accumulate on one of these infinitely thin plates and negative charges on the other.

My question is:

1. What are the two plates in a PN junction capacitor
2. And what are the positive and negative charges (analogy to a normal parallel plate cap, i.e the Q in Q=CV) - is it the separated positive and negative ions in the depletion region, or is it the free holes and electrons in the P and N regions?

Comment: The depletion region is the gap between plates. As its width varies, so does the capacitance.

Comment: @user_1818839 And what are the plates?

Comment: The boundaries between the conductive regions and th depletion region.

Answer (score 2):

The plates are the layers of the semiconductor material just outside the depletion region.

The positive charge in the n side is the ionized donor sites left behind when the free electrons are swept away, and the negative charge on the p side is the ionized acceptor sites left behind when the free holes are swept away as the depletion region grows due to increased applied reverse bias.

Comment: I don't understand. The 'ionized donor sites' left behind on the N side when electrons move away, I thought they are part of the depletion region itself? So how can it form the plate?

Comment: The two sides of the depletion region store opposite charges and have an electric field between them. Therefore they act like a capacitor. There doesn't have to be a physical "plate" for there to be a capacitive structure in an electronic device.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. One more thing, is there no capacitance due to the separation of charge inside the depletion region itself? I mean the above explanation makes sense if you consider the n-type material as one plate, the p-type material as another plate and the depletion region as a dielectric. But isn't the depletion region itself on it's own also an additional capacitor due to the separated positive(n-side of depletion) and negative ions (p-side of depletion) on each side ?